# Is there any word to describe a person who is always unlucky?

Tags: single-word-requests

Assuming an individual is always unlucky in all walks of life- education, relationship, employment etc.

Is there any word that can be used to describe such a person?

Comment: luckless, unfortunate, hapless or ill-fated

Comment: [Joe Btfsplk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Btfsplk) brings bad luck, but doesn't experience it himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like "jinxed" more than "loser."
How about **cursed** ? [Webster's ]
Synonyms include unlucky, unfortunate, and smote (as if by God). Slang: totally screwed, completely fu-ked-up life

Answer (score 2):

Consider **loser**:

> One that **fails consistently**, especially **a person with bad luck** or poor skills

(American Heritage Dictionary)

Another possibility is **jinxed**:

> someone or something that is jinxed has a **lot of bad luck**

([Macmillan English Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/jinxed))

A literary, Shakespearean word is **star-crossed**:

> star-crossed: if someone is star-crossed, they **keep having bad luck**.

(Collins Cobuild Dictionary)

> **dogged by ill luck**; destined to misfortune

(http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/star-crossed)

Answer (score 1):

One term I have heard to describe a person who is unlucky is "snake-bitten."

A "snakebite" is an unpleasant, sometimes fatal, event that appears to come out of nowhere.

Comment: My wife, who is from Georgia, uses "snakebit."

Answer (score 0):

back in the 70s & early 80s we called such a person a "mush". Because everything they touched (or bet on) was sure to turn to mush

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).